# Git Attributes Merge Ours

Tags: git, github, merge

I want not to merge a specific folder to another branch.

ex) `sample_folder/* merge=ours`

On single file, `index.php merge=ours` works fine. But no idea how to apply this to files inside of the folder.

Comment: I tried the same way as a single file but it's not working for me. Just wondering if something I'm missing!

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough:

```
sample_folder/ merge=ours
```

The [gitattributes man page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) explicitly mention

> Some of these settings can also be specified for a path, so that Git applies those settings only for a subdirectory or subset of files

Since the [Merge Strategies](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies) only mention files, you might have to tweak the file selector

```
sample_folder/*/* merge=ours 
# or
sample_folder/**/** merge=ours
```

Comment: I tested with gitignore and gitattributes, and gitignore is working fine with tree structure. However gitattributes is not working at all with folder structure. I tried
sample_folder/
sample_folder/**
sample_folder/*
sample_folder/test.php
sample_folder
/sample_folder
/sample_folder/
All of them were not working....
Did i miss something?

Comment: @SangLee what version of git are you using?

Comment: Version is git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)

Comment: @SangLee I'll have to check again (I am using 2.5.2)